# Regarding python MRO and how super() behaves

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, super, method-resolution-order

Today i was trying to figure out how `__mro__` and super works in python, I found something interesting as well as strange to me, because I got something which is not that i understood after reading `__mro__`. Here is the code snippets.

Code Snippets 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/pyhon

class A(object):
    def test(self):
        return 'A'

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        return 'B to %s' % super(B, self).test()

class C(A):
    def test(self):
        return 'C'

class D(B, C):
    pass

print D().test()
```

Output :

```
 B to C
```

Code snippet 2: When I update my super inside class B:

```
#!/usr/bin/pyhon

class A(object):
    def test(self):
        return 'A'

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        return 'B to %s' % super(C, self).test()

class C(A):
    def test(self):
        return 'C'

class D(B, C):
    pass

print D().test()
```

Output:

```
B to A
```

Then now i got what I expected before. Could someone please explain how mro works with super ?

Comment: I could've sworn a great explanation was already one of the first StackOverflow search hits for "Python super", but apparently not. None of them actually explain it; the best results just link to other sites.

Comment: Ya even i was trying to figure out from the various super blogs in stack as well as from google.

Comment: [Here's](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) the best explanation I've seen, and [here's](https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) a breakdown of some of `super`'s flaws.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that make me understand lots of stuff, that i din't know before :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MRO for D is [D, B, C, A, object].

`super(C, self)` ~ A

`super(B, self)` ~ C

`super(MyClass, self)` is not about the "base class of `MyClass`", but about the next class in the MRO list of `MyClass`.

As stated in the comments, `super(…)` actually does not return the next class in the MRO, but delegates calls to it.

Comment: So, if I change the `class D(B, C):` to `class D(C, B):` MRO will change to `D->C->B->A->Object` after that I tried for this `return 'B to %s' % super(B, self).test()` still getting the same output.

Comment: Didn't got it. If you still call `D().test()`, you get simply a `C` as output. `super(B, self).test()` is not even called.

Comment: Oops my bad, you are right, I forgot i ve another return 'C' from class C. So, I think you answer my Question. Thank you man.

Comment: Just to be clear, `super(C, self)` is a `super` object, that delegates the method calls to the next object in the MRO. It is _not_ that next object in the MRO as suggested by the answer. That is, in the first case `super(C, self) is A` will return False.

Comment: Thx, i change my answer accordingly.