# Why super call changes behaviour of calling init methods of parent classes?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

I've tried to read python `2.7` docs, but no chance to undestand unfortunately.

Why does that happening? How it is connected with MRO and super call inside of init?

First example:

```
class SuperFirst(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SuperFirst, self).__init__()
        print "We were in SuperFirst's __init__"

class SuperSecond(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SuperSecond, self).__init__()
        print "We were in SuperSecond's __init__"

class JustThird(SuperFirst, SuperSecond):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JustThird, self).__init__()
        print "We were in JustThird's __init__"

JustThird()
```

This outputs:

```
We were in SuperSecond's __init__
We were in SuperFirst's __init__
We were in JustThird's __init__
```

Now lets remove the super call inside of the init of the first parent:

```
class SuperFirst(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "We were in SuperFirst's __init__"

class SuperSecond(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SuperSecond, self).__init__()
        print "We were in SuperSecond's __init__"

class JustThird(SuperFirst, SuperSecond):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JustThird, self).__init__()
        print "We were in JustThird's __init__"

JustThird()
```

Output:

```
We were in SuperFirst's __init__
We were in JustThird's __init__
```

Now keep it only in the first parent:

```
class SuperFirst(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SuperFirst, self).__init__()
        print "We were in SuperFirst's __init__"

class SuperSecond(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "We were in SuperSecond's __init__"

class JustThird(SuperFirst, SuperSecond):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JustThird, self).__init__()
        print "We were in JustThird's __init__"

JustThird()
```

Output:

```
We were in SuperSecond's __init__
We were in SuperFirst's __init__
We were in JustThird's __init__
```

Now remove from both parents:

```
class SuperFirst(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "We were in SuperFirst's __init__"

class SuperSecond(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "We were in SuperSecond's __init__"

class JustThird(SuperFirst, SuperSecond):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JustThird, self).__init__()
        print "We were in JustThird's __init__"

JustThird()
```

Output:

```
We were in SuperFirst's __init__
We were in JustThird's __init__
```

Comment: A [really nice and short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545791/regarding-python-mro-and-how-super-behaves#answer-20546472)

Comment: What exactly don't you understand here? If there isn't a `super` call, the next implementation in the MRO doesn't get called and the chain stops.

Comment: @dhke thank you, so that's about MRO chain, not just base class...

Comment: @Alexezio You've got multiple inheritance, I'd say "base class" is everything after the current type in the MRO list.